# Query in SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

I'm creating a web application in VB.NET and ASP.NET.

Now I'm developing the report part.

I have imported an SSRS report in ASP.NET using the Report Viewer Control and then I create a specific report by changing, with a query, the `DataSet` of the SSRS report (this is done in VB.NET)

Since I want to create a general application (so that I can easily use this procedure in other future projects) I want to know if is possible to set the first part of the query `[SELECT * FROM TableName]` directly by the report file (`.rdlc`) and then create the where clause in the VB.NET file.

Can you help me ??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/b605e504-4031-4f6b-b22a-69e3f866cfae/

Yes. You can - using the @parameter_name value associated to the WHERE clause...

Comment: Do you now if is it possible to raed, by using vb.net, the query of the report (.rdl) dataSet? I was looking for the CommandText, but I have not understand how it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you now if is it possible to raed, by using vb.net, the query of the report (.rdl) dataSet?

I was looking for the CommandText, but I have not understand how it works